# Ant: resolve wildcards for java arg

Tags: java, ant, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I'm currently working on a pde build for a rcp application.
During the build I want to execute a .jar which requires the path to all plugins I use in my rcp application.
The Problem is the plugins all have a version at the end of their name.
e.g.: com.ibm.icu_52.1.1.v201501240615.jar

The .jar does not support wildcards in the argument so I tried using filelist and pathconvert:

```
<filelist id="plugins.jars"
    dir="${eclipse.pdebuild.home}.."
    files="com.ibm.icu*.jar,org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator*.jar"
/>

<pathconvert pathsep=";" property="plugins" refid="plugins.jars"/>

<java jar="Programm.jar"
        fork="true"
        failonerror="true">

        <arg value="${plugins}" />
</java>
```

The problem with that is that the * won't get resolved.

```
[java] Info: Setting additionally referenced classes (C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse_rcp\plugins\com.ibm.icu*.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse_rcp\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator*.jar).
[java] Error : Classpath file C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse_rcp\plugins\com.ibm.icu*.jar does not exist
```

Does anyone have an idee how I could solve this problem?

Any help is appreciated!

Best regards,
Andi

Comment: Check out the manifestclasspath task. Designed to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [fileset](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) instead :

```
<fileset dir="${eclipse.pdebuild.home}" id="plugins.jars"
  includes="com.ibm.icu*.jar,org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator*.jar/>

<!-- simple echo -->
<echo>${toString:plugins.jars}</echo>

<pathconvert pathsep=";" property="plugins" refid="plugins.jars"/>
```

Use ',' or blank as separator for includes.